# Unable to get Packery item layout order

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

I am trying to make a layout mixed width/fixed height boxes to work using Packery.

While I can get Packery to work, and lays things out fine — I need to know the order as presented on screen after the layout is completed (not the order of the DOM) so that I can do some tweaks to certain blocks if it is preceded by another specific block type.

I have three 'block sizes' — `100%`, `33.3333%` (1/3) and `66.6667%` (2/3). This means that, in some cases, if there's a narrow block (1/3) that'll fit next to smaller blocks further up, the blocks position on screen is different from the DOM (eg. up higher).

Basically I need this solution (refresh index/position of item after drag/drop) but on load: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mdJnF. This SO post also brings this up (slightly differently, and the solution is the same): [Determine the alignment order of the items with packery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591587/determine-the-alignment-order-of-the-items-with-packery)

When I try to implement the code to get the elements and their position, it just spits out the DOM order, throwing things out. I can't for the life of me work out why it's not working.

Reduced test case available here: https://jsfiddle.net/4q73tbwe/1/

Answer (score 1):

So, I worked out what the issue was.

By default the direction of layout is vertical. Defining the option `horizontal` to `true` solved the issue, and I now get the correct index number.